# JFace databinding bind field of parent class

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

I have a little problem with my databinding on a parent class.

This is the structure:

```
class Instrument{
    //some more fields
    private Entity e;

}

class Equity extends Instrument{
    //some fields (not someField)
}

class Entity{
    private String someField;
}
```

I want to call `PropertyDescriptor descriptor = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(model.getValue(), propertyName);`, where `model.getValue()` returns an object of type `Equity` and `propertyName` specifies the field name (`Instrument.e`).

I tried all kind of various approaches like:

- `super.e.someField`
- `e.someField`
- `instrument.e.someField`
- `someField`

It fails for every approach but the last with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'someField' on class 'class Equity'
```

Even though it doesn't throw that exception, it does not set any value even if there is one.

So my question is, how can I add databinding to my control on `Instrument.e.someField` from `Equity`?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but does setting the fields to `protected` change anything?

Comment: You mean `someField`?

Comment: Yes, and `Entity e`.

Comment: Didn't solve it. Still same error on `e.someField` and no error, but also no value on `someField`. It does work properly on a field that is specified by `Equity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just dumb as hell. I forgot to create getter and setter for `private Entity e;` in `Instrument` class. Once I added those, it worked just fine with `e.someField`